# I'm trying to send a POST request with Alamofire 4.0 & Swift 3, but the server receive GET parameters

Tags: swift3, alamofire, http-method, urlrequest

I'm trying to make a request sending parameters by POST, Alamofire request says that its POST, but my server get the parameters by GET.

```
    let formParams:[String : String] = ["facebook_id": COUtils.userProfile["id"]!, "full_name": name, "email": mail, "phone": phone , "state": state, "device_id": UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString, "device_type": "ios"]
    let headers = [
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": COUtils.autorizationBearer
    ]
    print(COUrls.apiUrl + COUrls.register, formParams)
    Alamofire.request(COUrls.apiUrl + COUrls.register, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: formParams, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        print(response.response?.allHeaderFields ?? "")
```

Thanks in advance